# How to get value from combobox from another page?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, navigationservice, getvalue

The person is choosing smth from combobox and I have to save this value and transport it to another page ?

```
public string ToAnotherWin() {
    k = comboboxPrices.SelectedItem.ToString();
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have written?

Comment: Well, what type of application is this? web/windows?

Comment: wpf application

Comment: public string ToAnotherWin()
        {
            k = comboboxPrices.SelectedItem.ToString();
            return k;

        }
I wanted to pass this method to another page but it failed

Comment: public string ToAnotherWin() { k = comboboxPrices.SelectedItem.ToString(); return k; } I wanted to pass this method to another page but it failed
@RobAnthony

Comment: Try using Global variables. So that you can store and access required variables across the application. You can use get / set property to assign and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

First create a class that stores your variable (`myVar`):

```
public class myData
{
    public string myVar { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a static class with a variable of type `myData` :

```
public static class allData
{
    public static myData myData {get;set;}
}
```

This allows you to call the variable `myVar` in another window.

If your `combobox` is positioned in the `MainWindow` your MainWindow constructor should look like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     comboBox.ItemsSource = new string[] { "aaa","smth","bbb" };
     allData.myData = new myData();
     DataContext = allData.myData;
}
```

The `combobox` xaml in the `MainWindow`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectedValue="{Binding myVar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

The Constructor of another window (eg. `Window1`) where you want to show the selected value of your combobox should look like this:

```
public Window1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = allData.myData;
}
```

For example if you want to show the selected value of the `combobox` as a `TextBlock` the xaml in this case looks like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding myVar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```